# The intersection of infinitely many dense open sets may not be dense

Tags: general-topology

I know that if $A$ and $B$ are dense open subsets of topological space $X$, then $A\cap B$ is also dense open. Furthermore, if $X$ is a Baire space, then the countable intersection of dense open subsets is still dense.

Let $X$ be any topological space and $\{A_{\alpha}\}$ is collection of dense open subsets of $X$. I know that $\bigcap_\alpha A_{\alpha}$ might not be dense, but I cannot find an example of this.

Answer (score 7):

Let $X=\mathbb{R}$ and for every $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$, define $A_\alpha=\mathbb{R}-\{\alpha\}$

Comment: Do it for $\mathbb{Q}$ and have a countable example.