# Infinite intersection of sets dense in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

I want to come up with an example where I've got a countably infinite number of sets $A_n$ which are all dense in $\mathbb{R}$. But where $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ is NOT dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

This was touched upon in this post: [The intersection of infinitely many dense open sets may not be dense](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1070410/the-intersection-of-infinitely-many-dense-open-sets-may-not-be-dense)

What has been said in that post is to define the sets $\ A_{q} = \mathbb{Q} \setminus \{q\}$, for every $q\in\mathbb{Q}$. Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable, there are a countable number of sets $A_{q}$.

The way I understand it, $\ A_{q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ for all $q\in \mathbb{Q}$.

We find that $\bigcap_{q\in\mathbb{Q}} A_{q} = \bigcap_{q\in\mathbb{Q}} \mathbb{Q} \setminus \{q\} = \mathbb{Q} \setminus \left( \bigcup_{q\in\mathbb{Q}} \{q\} \right) = \mathbb{Q} \setminus \mathbb{Q} = \emptyset$.

But $\emptyset$ is NOT dense in $\mathbb{R}$. So this is such an example.

Is my understanding of this correct? Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, this is fine.

Comment: It's worth noting, this example is important because any finite intersection of $A_q$ is still dense. It's easy to find a pair of sets with the above property: $B_1=\mathbb Q$ and $B_2=\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$. The interesting thing about this example is the fact about finite interesections.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is correct. It can already be achieved with two sets: $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q} + s$, where $s \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ is your favorite irrational number.